# get importer modules from within the module that is being imported

Tags: python, python-import

For example, i have 2 .py files `module1` and `module2`.

`module2` imports the `module1` using the `import` statement.

I want to have some way inside the `module1` to detect (from within the `module1` itself) which modules are importing it. in this case the module2 is importing it.

**What I did:**
if I import the `module1` from the `module2` I see that the `module1` have the `__loader__` and `__spec__` global vars. the `__loader__` contains the `<class '_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader'>`, the `__spec__` contains the `<class '_frozen_importlib.ModuleSpec'>` and the `__spec__.loader` is identical to the `__loader__`.

and if i write

```
print(__loader__.path)
```

inside the `module1`, it  gives the full path of the `module1`.

**What I want:**
I want some code inside the `module1` to get the path of `module2`. (not path of the `module1` which `__loader__.path` is giving).

Comment: I highly doubt if this is possible, since modules are loaded only once. So the second module that imports the same module will just get the cached object. If it would be possible, I guess it would be using the [import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) module. Did you check the documentation of that already? But most importantly, _why_ do you want this? I can't think of a good reason to do this. Maybe the question would be more useful if you provide a bit more context.

Answer (score 0):

Imports in Python are actually calls to functions in `importlib`, so you just need to get the information of the caller who calls functions in `importlib` by inspecting frames in the call stack.

However, which frame in the call stack is the actual caller's frame varies between Python versions due to different implementation details of the import system, so it's best that you iterate through the call stack and filter out the internal calls within `importlib`, which can be identified by filenames enclosed in angle brackets.

Once you find a frame whose filename does not start with an angle bracket, get its module information with `inspect.getmodule`:

```
import inspect

print(next(inspect.getmodule(f[0]).__file__
    for f in inspect.stack()[1:] if not f.filename.startswith('<')))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/LameAgonizingPrinters

Comment: Would this work if the module is imported multiple times (by different other modules)? Or does it only work for the first import?

Comment: Yes, you can use a list comprehension instead of a `next` call to get a full list of calling modules.

Comment: Hmm, I just tested this by creating two modules `foo.py` and `bar.py` that only do `import sub`, where `sub.py` is your above code. Then in `main.py` I wrote `import foo; import bar;`  When running `main.py`, the output includes only `foo.py`, not `bar.py`.

Comment: ```print(next(inspect.getmodule(f).__file__
    for f in inspect.stack()[1:] if f.filename[0] != "<"))``` giving me ```/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/inspect.py```

Comment: @wovano I thought you meant that the module has a grandparent importer when you mentioned a module imported multiple times but I now see what you mean. If the goal is to get every module that imports the module then you're right that this will not do it. So it's indeed up to the OP to clarify the use case.

Comment: ```for f in inspect.stack()[1:]:
 if f.filename[0] != "<":
  cm = inspect.getmodule(f)
  print(f"cfn={cfn}\ncmf={cm.__file__}\n")```
this gives me:

```cfn=/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py
cmf=/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/inspect.py

cfn=/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py
cmf=/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/inspect.py```

Comment: ```I understand that the iiec_run.py is being created by the pydroid3 when I run a module. instrad if running the module directly it creates a copy "iiec_run.py" and runs it. [atleat that is what I am guessing]```

Comment: this seems to do the job for me, or I dont know if its giving me illutions???.

I am using pydroid3 ide in my old android 7.0.

```#assuming its the last frame
print(next(reversed(inspect.stack())).frame.f_globals["__file__"])```

in which situations it can fall apart??